# Is a hyphen required after "much"?

Tags: commas, orthography, writing-style

Compare the two phrases:

`... at a much reduced price...`

versus

`... at a much-reduced price...`

Is a hyphen required here or it's unnecessary?

Comment: Please do not use the grammar tag on questions unrelated to syntax or morphology. Writing has nothing to do with grammar.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a question of preference. Compound adjectives are often hyphenated, but it's not *necessary*. Use a hyphen if it provides clarity, when not using one would be confusing.